# Asus Rampage IV Black edition wireless driver not working

Tags: wireless, madwifi

I'm new to Ubuntu I have installed Ubuntu on my computer everything seems to work fine but Wi-Fi. I was wondering if anyone know how can I install Wi-Fi drivers for Asus Rampage IV Black edition?  I ran this command in terminal `lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4`, it gave me the chipset of my wifi:

> **Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac wireless network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)**.

Any idea how can I get the driver from here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If its the driver issue please search for additional drivers in the Dash (the icon in the top left) for `Additional Drivers` and than search if you find a WiFi driver.

But some Notebooks simply have WiFi disabled to check this run

```
rfkill list
```

If you see `Soft Blocked: yes` near your WiFi run

```
sudo rfkill unblock <IDENTIFYER>
```

Where `IDENETIFYER` is the number of your WiFi, `all` or `wifi`

Comment: Thanks info-screen, I tried rfkill list but my wifi doesn't show there. I ran this command in terminal lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4, it gave me the chipset of my wifi : Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac wireless network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03). Any idea how can I get the driver from here?

Comment: what's about the additional drivers?